# converting dec-numbers to binary code with a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, binary

I work on a program. You can enter a normal number and the program should convert it first in binary code and then copy it into a string. If I start program and enter a number nothing happens.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   int i;
    unsigned short input;
    char output [18] = "";

    printf("enter a positive number\n");

    scanf("%hu", &input);

    for (i= 16; 1; i-- )
       {
          output [i] =  input % 2;

        input = input / 2;

       }

     puts(output);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because `'1' != 1`

Comment: `for (i= 16; 1; i-- )` will loop forever.

Comment: Did you even try to debug this?

Comment: '1' != 1 you mean that a char != int ?

Comment: But why should it loop forever?

Comment: It will loop forever because the 1 always is seen as true. Perhaps you meant `for (i= 16; i  > 1; i-- ) But even that will not fix your broken logic, since you never fill a value for output[0].

Comment: an `int` is usually is 32-bit wide. So, you will not be able to fit it in the *18* binary chars.

Answer (score 0):

`output` should be NUL terminated, so you need 16 bytes for `short int` plus 1 for null-character

```
char output [17];
```

Add the ASCII value of `0` to the result to obtain `0` or `1`

```
for(i = 16; i >= 0; i--)
{
    output[i] = '0' + input % 2;
    input = input / 2;
}
```

Finally add the null-character:

```
output[16] = 0;
```

Alternatively you can use the shift operator

```
unsigned int bitmask = 1 << (15 - i);
output[i] = '0' + ((input & bitmask) ? 1 : 0);
```